# Consulta iconos en tablayout en un fragment

Tags: android-studio

Muy buenas estimada comunidad y esperando que todos se encuentren muy bien,e stoy realizando mi primera aplicación con fragment, y viendo se ppueden colocar iconos para que el usuario los pueda ver e dentificar con su nombre, ahora baje unos iconos gratos de la web, los cuales son los siguientes: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y este es el código del xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".archivos.Frmpresupuesto">

<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tablayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#7B1FA2">

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
        android:id="@+id/ingreso"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Ingreso"
        android:icon="@drawable/ingresar"/>

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
        android:id="@+id/mano"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Mano"
        android:icon="@drawable/mano"/>

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
        android:id="@+id/repuestos"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Repuestos"
        android:icon="@drawable/repuestos"/>

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
        android:id="@+id/resumen"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Resumen"
        android:icon="@drawable/resumen"/>
</com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>

<androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

al momento de ejecutar la app en el emulador los iconos antes mostrados están en color negro y difusos, hay alguna manera de poder solucionar este problema que hay, desde ya muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comentas lo siguiente "los iconos antes mostrados están en color negro y difusos", esto puede deberse a que usas imágenes que no son aptas para tu aplicación, pueden ser imágenes con una resolución muy baja o de un formato inadecuado, que en algunos dispositivos se verán correctamente pero en otros no. Para que se vean correctamente las imágenes que muestras deberías tener varios formatos y agregarlos a los directorios de tu aplicación de las distintas densidades, sin embargo, esto ya no es una práctica recomendada.

Recuerda las especificaciones que se tienen que seguir para la creación de iconos requeridos en las aplicaciones.

[Especificaciones de diseño de íconos](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/create-app-icons?hl=es-419)

**Te sugiero que actualmente uses imágenes .svg en tu aplicación, esto para que se muestren correctamente en cualquier tamaño y densidad de pantalla del dispositivo.**

Las imágenes SVG se tienen que agregar a tu proyecto como "Vector Asset". Para agregar imágenes .svg como "Vector Asset" a tu proyecto, da clic derecho en el proyecto, selecciona <kbd>New</kbd> y <kbd>Vector Asset</kbd>

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ubica y carga tu archivo dando clic al icono del directorio

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí puedes definir un nombre para la imagen, así como su tamaño y opacidad requerida

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al final simplemente define la ubicación de tu archivo (se guardará con extensión .xml) que generalmente es en `/drawable`

---

Para obtener iconos te recomiendo

https://fonts.google.com/icons

https://m2.material.io/

Donde puedes obtener los iconos en formato .svg, .png que puedes usar en tu app.

Otras fuentes para obtener iconos son:

https://icons8.com/icons/material

https://mui.com/material-ui/material-icons/